# MySQL Update entire table with unknown # of rows and clear the rest

Tags: mysql

I'm pretty sure this particular quirk isn't a duplicate so here goes.

I have a table of services.  In this table, I have about 40 rows of the following columns:

```
Services:
  id_Services -- primary key
  Name -- name of the service
  Cost_a -- for variant a of service
  Cost_b -- for variant b of service
  Order -- order service is displayed in
```

The user can go into an admin tool and update any of this information - including deleting multiple rows, adding a row, editing info, and changing the order they are displayed in.

My question is this, since I will never know how many rows will be incoming from a submission (there could be 1 more or 100% less), I was wondering how to address this in my query.

Upon submission, every value is resubmitted.  I'd hate to do it this way but the easiest way I can think of is to truncate the table and reinsert everything... but that seems a little... uhhh... bad!  What is the best way to accomplish this?

**RE-EDIT:**  For example: I start with 40 rows, update with 36.  I still have to do something to the values in rows 37-40. How can I do this? Are there any mysql tricks or functions that will do this for me?

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: I don't understand the problem. You have the primary key column `id_Services`, and your user can't change that ID. When the user provides new data with a given ID, `UPDATE` the data for that ID.

Comment: It sounds like you have two possible updates. One, the user edits using admin tool. Everything works fine. Two, there is a submission and something else happens. Is this where the issue lies? What happens when there is a submission?

Comment: @Tomalak - I'm using the column Order to determine the order in which the rows are displayed, the primary key isn't being touched.

Comment: @MJB - the issue is the discrepancy between what is in the database (for example 40 rows) and a submission to update of less than 40 rows (if the user deletes rows) which would leave old values in the last remaining rows (for example rows 40, 39, 38, etc...).  Oh boy... I wish I didn't suck @ english!  Hope that helps clarify.

Comment: @Rohjay: The ID column identifies rows. Use it to... identify rows.

Comment: @Tomalak - Thanks for your help - I really do appreciate it.  I understand I can use the pk for identifying rows.  I guess I'm trying to say, if I update with fewer rows - I start with 40, update with 36, I still have to do something to the values in rows 37-40.  How can I do this or do I need multiple queries?

Comment: When the user deletes 4 rows, identify them (by their `id_Services` key) and delete them too. If the user updates the rest 36 rows, update the rest 36 too.

Comment: @Rohjay: No you don't. Why do you have to?

Comment: @Tomalak - Here's why; so far I have 40 rows, the user chooses to remove 4 and changes values and other edits to rows 1-36. If I just update rows 1-36 with their new values, that information will be fine, but then I have 37-40 remaining.  Is there a way to just trim those off the end or must I do a 2nd query to remove them?

Comment: @Rohjay: I think I see. It's possibly a slightly peculiar way to do it. Anyway, yea, if you want to remove entries at the same time as inserting/updating entries, well.. you can't. You'll need a separate `DELETE FROM` statement.

Comment: @Tomalak - Thanks for your patience with me. I'm a newbie to MySQL so I'm not sure about any tricks or advanced usages for it.  Put that up as an answer and I'll select it man!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're slightly limited by the use case; you're doing insertion/update/truncation that's presented to the user as a batch operation, but in the back-end you'll have to do these in separate statements.

Watch out for concurrency: use transactions if you can.